# Counting data from 3 tables with tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to count how many times instruments are used every year:

I got 3 tabels: procedures p, instruments i, instrument_types t these are linked as followed:

p contains a the primary_no of i and i contains the primary_no of t.

How can i count how many times a type is used ?

Comment: Explain better your schema.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: we need more information on your tables.

Comment: Based on your limited information I would suggest a SELECT  COUNT(primary_no) and a GROUP BY primary_no

Answer (score 0):

Had to make some guesses on what the columns were called.  Hope these names make enough sense for you to work with

```
Select
        T.Type_Desc
    ,   I.Instr_Desc
    ,   Count(P.*)  Usage_Count
From
        Procedures          P
Inner
Join    Instrument          I
    On  I.P_FK              =   P.PK
Inner
Join    Instrument_Type T
    On  T.T_FK              =   T.PK
Group
    By  T.Type_Desc
    ,   I.Instr_Desc
```

Let me know if this works for you.